# Reference for statement relating homeomorphisms of a space and homomorphisms of fundamental group?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm looking for a reference for the following statement. I expected to find it in Hatcher (Algebraic Topology) but I can't spot it. I have written it here to the best of my ability but I have undoubtedly made some mistakes.

The statement is that if $(X,x_0)$ and $(Y,y_0)$ are pointed topological spaces, then there is a bijection
$$Homeo((X,x_0), (Y,y_0))\to Hom(\pi_1(X,x_0),\pi_1(Y,y_0))$$
between the set of (homotopy classes of?) homeomorphisms between them and the set of homomorphisms between their fundamental groups. Moreover, if we drop the points, we have a bijection
$$Homeo(X, Y)\to Hom(\pi_1(X),\pi_1(Y))/Inn(\pi_1(X))$$
between homeomorphisms and homomorphisms up to inner automorphism.

If you have any idea what I am talking about, please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure? An homeomorphism will always induce an isomorphism of fundamental groups, so there is no hope to have surjectivity. I don't know if replacing $\mathrm{Hom}$ with $\mathrm{Isos}$ is sufficient to have surjectivity, though. Also, you probably have to quotient the LHS up to homotopy if you want injectivity.

Comment: Even that will not be enough. The existence of an isomorphism of fundamental groups means basically nothing about the spaces, and it certainly does not imply that they are homeomorphic, or even homotopically equivalent.

Comment: One corollary of this would be that all spaces are homeomorphic, because no matter what $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ and $\pi_1(Y,y_0)$ are, the set $Hom(\pi_1(X,x_0),\pi_1(Y,y_0))$ is not empty (take the homomorphism which sends all of $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ to the identity element of $\pi_1(Y,y_0)$. Therefore, $Homeo((X,x_0),(Y,y_0))$ is not empty.

Comment: It's not true that $[X,Y]=\mathrm{Hom}(\pi_1X,\pi_1Y)$ either. Maybe you were thinking of $K(G,1)$ spaces?

Comment: Thanks for all the quick responses, it's clear that I'm missing some context. We would certainly be considering homotopy classes of homeomorphisms, the map from left to right taking a map to its induced homomorphism. I am also specifically thinking of hyperbolic surfaces

Comment: I think hyperbolic surfaces are aspherical, aren't they? So you are probably in the fortunate case of $K(G, 1)$ spaces.

Comment: yeah I think this statement is roughly true for $K(G,1)$ maybe google mapping class group of $K(G,1)$ spaces. Every hyperbolic surface is an example since their universal cover is contractible

Comment: I also don’t mean Homeo, I’m looking at immersions of one surface inside another (so continuous not bi-continuous). I’m getting closer to the right statement, I’ll post it here if I find the right reference